# Xdmx and glx acceleration not working

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, xdmx

I am using [Xdmx](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/) (Now built into Xorg) to span a four monitor XServer over two PCs each running two monitors.

Both PCS are running Arch Linux and identical versions of software, and have ATI graphics cards (although differing ages).

I am unable to get GLX acceleration working at all using the ATI open source driver and have not had any success with the closed source one either. This means that in general it performs pretty badly.

My xorg log is full of:

```
(**) dmx: dmxErrorHandler: BadName (named color or font does not exist)
(**) dmx:                  Major opcode: 156 (RENDER)
(**) dmx:                  Minor opcode: 30 (RenderSetPictureFilter)
(**) dmx:                  ResourceID:   0x602d93
(**) dmx:                  Failed serial number:  182593
(**) dmx:                  Current serial number: 182788
```

On a side note after a few hours use it all slows down to a crawl for no apparent reason (not high CPU or RAM usage). I then have to restart Xdmx to get it to be fast again.

This is very annoying.

Does anyone have any experience or success getting GLX working in Xdmx?

Alternatively does anyone know of a modern alternative to Xdmx that works instead as it seems that hardly anyone uses Xdmx any more?

Comment: It looks to me like you don't have GLX working properly for reasons that have nothing to do with Xdmx, what's your output from glxinfo?

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe this bug: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34851

You can use [chromium as a glx proxy for xdmx](http://chromium.sourceforge.net/doc/dmx.html). Speaking from experience, it works, but is a pain in the ass to get it working....

Answer (score 0):

"Alternatively does anyone know of a modern alternative to Xdmx that works instead as it seems that hardly anyone uses Xdmx any more?"

Have you tried simply installing both ATI cards in one machine?

Depending on whether you care about being able to drag windows between screens you could use a combo of synergy and VNC/XDMCP/etc...